# Org mode: Scheduling irregular, yet rigid procedures

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-capture

### The Problem

What's the best way to schedule complicated time-based procedures that are repeated on irregular dates? E.g., say I signed up to do night watch on a set of arbitrary dates. The night watch procedure requires certain actions at certain times:

```
* Night Watch <2023-07-10 18:00>--<2023-07-11 09:00>
** TODO Rounds 
SCHEDULED: <2023-07-10 19:00>
** TODO Call in
SCHEDULED: <2023-07-10 22:00>
```

Is there an easy way to have "Night Watch" and its children show up on the agenda on any arbitrary set of dates (i.e, with no pattern)?

### What I've tried

1. I found one question where an org-capture template was loaded with a handmade script that prompted for a date and manipulated the dates--but unfortunately they did not include an example of adding a time range to an input date, and I couldn't figure out how from the onboard documentation.

Comment: Not an answer, just a clarification. These look like appointments to me: you should probably use (active) timestamps only. See [Deadlines and Scheduling](https://orgmode.org/manual/Deadlines-and-Scheduling.html) in the manual, in particular the `Important` note at the end of the `SCHEDULED` description: note that `SCHEDULED` does not mean what you might normally think it means.

Comment: I did read that note; that's why "night duty" has a plain timestamp range and the two tasks (upon which would be my duty to do at some point within a certain timeframe) are `SCHEDULED`. Unless there's a more "canonical" way to format such things?

Comment: `SCHEDULED` tasks are meant to be done at *or after* the stated time. The agenda will keep reminding you until they are marked DONE. If that's what you want, then that's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that no, this isn't possible. The reason it isn't possible is that the agenda view has to read the data from org-mode files, so the data has to be there.

Org provides a function, `org-clone-subtree-with-time-shift`, which you can copy multiple times with a given time shift, e.g. `+1d`. Obviously, it can only create regular intervals, but it can be a starting point.

For instance, I called it to make two clones at one day intervals : `M-x org-clone-subtree-with-time-shift RET 2 RET +1d` and I got this:

```
* Night Watch <2023-07-10 18:00>--<2023-07-11 09:00>
** TODO Rounds 
SCHEDULED: <2023-07-10 19:00>
** TODO Call in
SCHEDULED: <2023-07-10 22:00>
* Night Watch <2023-07-11 Tue 18:00>--<2023-07-12 Wed 09:00>
** TODO Rounds 
SCHEDULED: <2023-07-11 Tue 19:00>
** TODO Call in
SCHEDULED: <2023-07-11 Tue 22:00>
* Night Watch <2023-07-12 Wed 18:00>--<2023-07-13 Thu 09:00>
** TODO Rounds 
SCHEDULED: <2023-07-12 Wed 19:00>
** TODO Call in
```

Based on a somewhat cursory examination of the code, it looks like it uses this pattern to update all the relevant dates (that is, starting and ending dates of a range):

```
(while (re-search-forward org-ts-regexp-both nil t)
              (org-timestamp-change 1 'day))
```

So you could use this to write your own code.

It might be simpler, however, to just call `org-clone-subtree-with-time-shift` multiple times to create multiple single copies. Anything `irregular` is best done by a human being.

Comment: This seems like a good answer. Perhaps I could make a derivative of `org-clone-subtree-with-time-shift` that allows the input of an absolute date or even series of dates. It would be a good feature to have an event repeat on a given set of dates, and have children able to inherit (partial) date/time data from their parents--maybe eventually I can make a package for that.